# Xpages Dynamic View panel scrollbar

Tags: xpages-extlib

I have xpages with dynamic view panel which I need to have horizontal scrollbar.  Can anyone tell be how to get the scroll bar,
Thanks

It appear to be something in the ExtLib application layout causing the scroll bar not to appear. When I create a XPage without the application layout the scroll bar appears.

The complete code is too long to post but here a simple version. ccLayout contains the Application Layout component.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    xmlns:xc="ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xc:ccLayout
        titleBarTabsRender="true"
        placeBarRender="true">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:label
                    value="Label"
                    id="label1">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:panel>
            <xe:dynamicViewPanel
                id="dynamicViewPanel1"
                pageName="/xpTIRdoc.xsp">
                <xe:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoView
                        var="view1"
                        databaseName="TIRv20Test.nsf"
                        viewName="vwXPTIRDetail">
                    </xp:dominoView>
                </xe:this.data>
            </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
        </xp:panel>
    </xc:ccLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.lotusContent` class which is applied to a div in the application layout has css overflow hidden. When this is changed to `overflow: auto` the scroll bar appears.